# sbpl_lattice_planner not recognizing location of sbpl

Tags: ros, sbpl-lattice-planner, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install sbpl_lattice_planner.  I have previously installed the motion_planners stack and had a successful rosmake for the sbpl package.  When I do a rosmake for sbpl_lattice_planner I get an error that it cannot find sbpl.

```
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sbpl_lattice_planner [ make ]                          
[ rosmake ] All 18 linesbpl_lattice_planner: 2.2 ... [ 1 Active 35/36 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package sbpl_lattice_planner
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
  -- checking for module 'sbpl'
  --   package 'sbpl' not found
  CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
    A required package was not found
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:320 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
    CMakeLists.txt:15 (pkg_check_modules)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package sbpl_lattice_planner written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/matt/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121017-100717/sbpl_lattice_planner/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished
```

I have read comments and answers on [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/37897/sbpllatticeplannerstatsh-file-not-found/) and [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/36449/sbpl_lattice_planner-on-fuerte/) but the solution to the first was to install sbpl (done) and the second isn't exactly the same thing as my problem.  I did try adding sbpl to the manifest.xml for sbpl_lattice_planner, but that didn't help either.

What am I missing?  Is there something that I need to do in order to get pkg_check_modules to work correctly?

I'm running fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04 with the packages installed in a ros_workspace directory instead of in opt/ros/fuerte.  I'm using rosws to set and update the packages and remembering to source the setup.bash before doing the rosmake.

Also, would someone please upvote this so I can get the Karma to comment?  I would have added this as a comment to the first question linked above, but I don't have the points yet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46103/sbpl_lattice_planner-not-recognizing-location-of-sbpl/) by [MattL](https://answers.ros.org/users/3107/mattl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-10-17

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MattL](https://answers.ros.org/users/3107/mattl/) on 2012-10-19**:
An update, I installed sbpl using "sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-sbpl".  It installed libraries in the opt/ros/fuerte/include directory, but did not install anything else.  Also, roscd and rospack cannot find sbpl.  All that being said, it was somehow possible for sbpl_lattice_planner to rosmake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What I did to solve this install sbpl_lattice_planner package with rosws. I also downloaded sbpl package and used rosws to install it. After this, the make for the lattice planner completed and found sbpl.
When you run it, stage might crash, but this is because their world is outdated (uses laser instead of ranger in stage...)

---

Originally posted by [pmolina](https://answers.ros.org/users/2919/pmolina/) with karma: 108 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0